# C# WEB API: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, sockets, asp.net-web-api

I am building one service which hit the another external web api endpoint to fetch the data using HttpClient PostAsync method.
I am building the service in .net framework 4.6.1, everything is working fine at **localhost** but when I move the code to Test environment I am getting the below error.

> **System.Net.WebException**: Unable to connect to the remote server **System.Net.Sockets.SocketException**: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond **XX.XX.XXX.XX:443**.
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)

My code is hosted in **AWS** and web api I am consuming is also hosted in another AWS.

**What will be cause of this error?**

Is Firewall blocking that communication?

Comment: Yes, looks like !

Comment: On AWS, hope your machine which is trying to connect, is in authorized IP list.

Comment: @AbhayDesai I checked the whitelsiting of IP, IP is whitelisted on AWS. But API is hosted behind a gateway so do I need to whitelist both gateway and actual machine IP.

Comment: Got the answer to problem: I have to raise trhe request to the API team so that they can allow my NAT gateway address at there end.